# SQL simple statement to get values does not work correctly

Tags: php, sql

Basically, I try to fetch player id
it outputs id 17 it's a correct number
and I'm pretty sure it's correct to there. Then use these values to get a list of trade info.
The database looks like this:

[image]
The PHP function that I call

```
function listtrade() {
    
    
    global $db;
    $damnid = usertouserid($usernick);
    //SQL queries really suck dude
    $dt = "SELECT * FROM trades WHERE tradereceiver = '$damnid' ORDER BY tradeid DESC";
    $dbdata = array();
    $tsr = mysqli_query($db, $dt);
    while ($dbdatadt = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tsr)) {
        $dbdata[] = $dbdatadt;
    }
    return $dbdata;

}
```

Steps I tried

1. adding and removing `'`
2. removing `order by`

but it does not solve, any reason this happens?
It looks very dumb for me, it should run correctly, the syntax is correct.

Comment: Where is `$usernick` set?

Comment: this is test code not used in production. everything is in prepared statements just for testing before trying prepared statements.

Comment: i have a function gathers user id from db. Returns correctly fine too. 17 is expected result and result is 17. Usernick set in header.php file takes it from session. Given username checked on db converts to id (tested fine) but it does not do main statement correctly

Comment: But it's not set within this function.

Comment: If it's a global variable you need `global $usernick;`

Comment: can you explain this "$dbdata[] = $dbdatadt" , did you mean to use array_push ?

Comment: yes true its not set in this function but its exists beacuse from other queries i did it does them correctly just this one for some reason fails (copying pasting code from other queries dont solve too if i use tradereceiver

Comment: @RedaBourial That's standard PHP syntax, it's the same as `array_push()`.

Comment: yes thank you global is thing i forgot

Comment: Maybe you should get out of the habit of using global variables. Pass everything as parameters.

Comment: actually you saying right. Im coming from csharp side i thought its pretty similar and i forget sometimes you need global blahblah; and sometimes i try to define variables like string $variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below things:
1. global $db;->print this, check the connection is correct?
2. $damnid = usertouserid($usernick);-> print this getting value 17?
3. Check table name 'trades' exists in database?
4. $usernick is not defined in your code, it seems?

Comment: This content (asking for clarification) is fitting for a comment, not an answer. Once you have [sufficient reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), you'll be able to comment on other people's posts, but in the meantime, please avoid using the answer space to get around this limitation.

Comment: Thanks for the information, i will follow!

Comment: thanks really helpful